# error At least one of ID token and access token is need flutter googlecalendarApi

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-api

I am making a Flutter app that allows users to make bookings for services in a store, I want to add each booking to the admins google calendar when when I try I get the following error:

```
oviders/google_auth.dart': Failed assertion: line 43 pos 12: 'accessToken != null || idToken != null': At least one of ID token and access token is required
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
#2      GoogleAuthProvider.credential (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/providers/google_auth.dart:43:12)
#3      DBHandler.signInWithGoogle (package:mona/services/auth/db_handler.dart:38:43)
```

This is the code for Adding the event:

```
   //This will get called when we create a booking in this class
      Future<void> addBookingToAdminCalendar(DateTime bookingDate,
          DateTime startTime, Duration duration, String title) async {
        //I want the title of the service as well as the bookingDate, StartTime and duration put into the admins google Calendar
        const _scopes = const [CalendarApi.calendarScope];
        var _credentials;
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          _credentials = ClientId(
              "804864006155-nqspt6dghao70s2sam1p0o3gjl0ira8e.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "");
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          _credentials = ClientId(
              "804864006155-occoeq4bhrq8cufagcrt844kbg3irjq5.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "");
        }
    
        final event = calendar.Event()
          ..summary = '$title Booking'
          ..start = calendar.EventDateTime(dateTime: startTime)
          ..end = calendar.EventDateTime(
            dateTime: startTime.add(duration),
          );
    
        final adminCalendarId = 'jondoe@gmail.com'; // Admin's email
    
        try {
          clientViaUserConsent(_credentials, _scopes, prompt)
              .then((AuthClient client) {
            var calendar = CalendarApi(client);
            calendar.events.insert(event, adminCalendarId).then((value) {
              print("ADDEDDD_________________${value.status}");
              if (value.status == "confirmed") {
                print('event added in google calendar');
              } else {
                print("Unable to add event in google calendar");
              }
            });
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error creating event $e');
        }
      }
    
      void prompt(String url) async {
        if (await canLaunch(url)) {
          await launch(url);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
      }
```

The user can sign in either with email of google sign in, I make sure the user is signed in before they can even use the app and I have gone through all of the necessary steps to setup google calendar api. what could be causing the error?